# dereference pointer always prints 0

Tags: pointers

I'm trying to figure out why dereferencing my pointer always prints 0. I put in other print statements to make sure random() is working correctly, and it does.

```
int * first = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * N);
    while( i < N) 
          first[i++] = random();
          printf("%d", first[i]);
    }
```

I even assigned the values of first to another array and those values matched the ones returned by random(). Why does my print statement in this while loop always print 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      first[i++] = random();
      printf("%d", first[i]);
```

Assuming i is 0, with these two lines you are assigning a value to the first element of the array:

```
first[0] = random();
```

incrementing the index:

```
i++
```

then printing the value in the second element of the array:

```
printf("%d", first[1]);
```

If you make the incrementing of the index explicit it should be clearer:

```
while (i < N)
{
      first[i] = random();
      printf("%d", first[i]);
      i++;
}
```

(You also appeared to have missed the opening bracket (`{`) but that could be a typo in the question)

Comment: @Elizabeth - we've all been there.